# Windows 10 PC communicating on two networks

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I have a laptop with with a single NIC and an IP Address of 10.7.1.182. I can talk to another system, 10.7.1.199, no problem. Of course, same network. But I cannot talk to a system with an address of 10.16.1.200. Naturally, not on the same network. Snooping the LAN the laptop is not even trying to find 10.16.1.200! No ARPs, no nothing. I am pretty sure a route is needed to get him to try and talk to 10.16.1.200. Can't use static IP Addresses unfortunately.

Will setting a route into the laptop route table solve this and if so what would it look like?

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368707) might be useful

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of the network mask, your laptop makes a routing decision for any outgoing packet. Assuming a /24 network, any address 10.7.1.0 to 10.7.1.255 is considered local - ARPed and sent to directly. Anything else is considered non-local and sent to the default gateway, or a better one, depending on the local routing table. Without any matching route, the packet is dropped.

So, either your default gateway has a route to 10.16.1.200 - then everything should be working - or you need to set up a route using a different gateway.

If 10.16.1.200 is located on the same L2 segment you could make your laptop send to it directly (`route add 10.16.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0`), or decrease the mask length to at least /19 (or 255.192.0.0) to encompass the destination. Of course, you'll need to do the same on the destination to find the way back.

Alternatively, you could add an IP address from 10.16.1.0/24 to your NIC.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I will try this.